# How to use Spring Security form authentication without using JSP taglibs?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am not using JSPs as my templating engine, but I want to use Spring Security (in Spring Boot). I use Handlebars for Java, which can get model variables (just like JSPs), but I don't have the JSP taglib to do the wiring for me.

I've been looking around on how to create a form for login, but can't find much. I don't know what URL shall I post the form to and I think there are special hidden parameters: in one example I've seen `_csrf.parameterName` and `_csrf.token`. But they don't end up in the model seen by my template.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you need to do a post to j_spring_security_check servlet with j_username and j_password parameters. eg. http://<context>/j_spring_security_check?j_username=name&j_password=password.

Comment: Not if you use Spring Security Java config with the default settings (you should post to /login with username and password).

Comment: I guess you need to look at the way the model is created for your template. Spring Security adds "_csrf" as a request attribute (which means it is added to all Spring MVC templates, but yours must be something different).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application.properties:

```
handlebars.exposeRequestAttributes=true
```

Then you should be able to access from your template like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{_csrf.parameterName}}" value="{{_csrf.token}}"/>
```